# Validation with Hapi.js and Bookshelf.js issues

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, bookshelf.js

I am following the `login` example they give on the bookshelf.js (http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model) website, but for some reason my code is returning a 200 response regardless of whether I submit a bad password or not

Here is my route:

```
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/auth/login',
        config: {
            auth: false,
            payload: { allow: 'application/json' },
            handler: function(request, reply) {
                var email = request.payload.email;
                var pwd = request.payload.password;

                User.login(email, pwd).then(function(user) {
                    reply(user.pick('api_token'));
                }).catch(User.NotFoundError, function() {
                    reply({error: email + ' not found'}).code(400)
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            },
            validate: {
                payload: Joi.object().keys({
                    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
                    password: Joi.string().required()
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
'use strict';

var Bluebird = require('bluebird');
var bcrypt = Bluebird.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt'));


module.exports = function(bookshelf) {
    var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'user',
    }, {
        login: Bluebird.method(function(email, password) {
            return new this({email: email.toLowerCase().trim()})
                .fetch({require: true})
                .tap(function(user) {
                    return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, user.get('encrypted_password'));
                });
        })
    });

    return User;
};
```

I'm not sure whats going on. I `console.log`ged the response from comparing the passwords on both a good request and a bad one and that piece of code is working, but like I said, even if I submit a bad password, the user is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the docs are wrong here.

You're not doing anything with the result of `compareAsync`. It returns a promise resolving to a bool (docs [here](https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs)).

So you probably want to do something like this:

Create an error class somewhere. I'm using 'create-error' module that is used by Bookshelf.

```
InvalidPasswordError = require('create-error')('InvalidPasswordError');
```

Now fire this error when the password does not match.

```
login: Bluebird.method(function(email, password) {
  return new this({email: email.toLowerCase().trim()})
    .fetch({require: true})
    .tap(function(user) {
      return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, user.get('encrypted_password'))
        .then(function (matches) {
          if (!matches) throw new InvalidPasswordError();
        }
    });
})
```

Now catch that error by type and respond with the appropriate error.

```
handler: function(request, reply) {
  var email = request.payload.email;
  var pwd = request.payload.password;

  User.login(email, pwd).then(function(user) {
    reply(user.pick('api_token'));
  }).catch(User.NotFoundError, function() {
    reply({error: email + ' not found'}).code(400);
  }).catch(InvalidPasswordError, function() {
    reply({error: 'invalid password'}).code(400);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
},
```

Comment: this line `return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, user.get('encrypted_password'));` should probably be without the semicolon

Comment: This worked great, thank you!!! I ended up using the Boom npm package for error handling, but really looking forward to diving into Bookshelf.js!

Answer (score 2):

I think Rhys van der Waerden provided a good solution. However, to figure out what's wrong with your code, consider this (from the bluebird specifications):

```
getUser().tap(function(user) {
    //Like in finally, if you return a promise from the handler
    //the promise is awaited for before passing the original value through
    return recordStatsAsync();
}).then(function(user) {
    //user is the user from getUser(), not recordStatsAsync()
});
```

As you can see, `.then` case gets the complete result, the async part of the `.tap` does not provide the data for `.then`.

Long story short: change from `.tap` to `.then` and you should be good. However, the result you'll get will be either `true` or `false` and not the user data.